SA_RESETHAND flag in sigaction not working for swift exceptions
I have an exception handling frame for an Xcode application in macOS, which contains Cpp and Swift code. I am using the Unix signals frame for handling exceptions using sigaction. My sigaction signal handler get invoked when there is a swift or Cpp exception. However for some exceptions like SIGSEGV, the signal handler gets called repeatedly. To handle this I am using the SA_RESETHAND flag so that the handler gets invoked only once, and then the default action for the signal take over to terminate the process.
This approach works well when an exception occurs due to Cpp code, however when it occurs due to Swift code, the signal handler still gets invoked repeatedly. Can someone explain why is this happening and What is the solution to this?

I happened to notice this Cosmopolitan libc commit that explains the bug: https://github.com/jart/cosmopolitan/commit/793393a3413f7c7b781fc88750e6c2659af9b56f

Apple's documentation
claims to support this feature, but they only define the constant in
their header files. The kernel acknowledges thi SA_RESETHAND bit, by
clearing it from the sa_flags state, returns zero, and does nothing.

You could probably work around the bug with something like this:
int signal_handler(int sig) {
    static volatile sig_atomic_t called = 0;
    if (called) {
        signal(sig, SIG_DFL);
        raise(sig);
    }
    called = 1;

    // Your code here
}

The above only works correctly if you use a different signal handler function for each signal.
